# Comparator in template

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I need to store and compare different types of (struct CElem in class CSearch). I do not know how to achieve the same iterators for comparison in the function Search.

```
if (comp(*t, *it))
```

This condition can not use iterators are the same type, can you advise?

```
    template <typename _Type, typename _Comparator = equal_to<typename _Type::value_type> >
    class CSearch {
public:
    CSearch() : comp(_Comparator()) {
    };

    CSearch(const _Comparator &_cmp) : comp(_cmp) {
    };
    void Add(int id,
            const _Type & needle);
    set<int> Search(const _Type & hayHeap) const;
private:

    struct CElem {
        int id;
        _Type seq;
    };
    vector<CElem> m_Data;
    _Comparator comp;
};

template <typename _Type, typename _Comparator>
void CSearch<_Type, _Comparator>::Add(int id, const _Type& needle) {
    CElem temp;
    temp.id = id;
    temp.seq = needle;
    m_Data.push_back(temp);
}

template <typename _Type, typename _Comparator>
set<int> CSearch<_Type, _Comparator>::Search(const _Type & hayHeap) const {
    set<int> stmp;
    typename _Type::const_iterator t;
    typename vector<CElem>::const_iterator it;
    for (t = hayHeap.begin(); t != hayHeap.end(); ++t){        
            //cout << *hayHeap << endl;
            for(it=m_Data.begin(); it!=m_Data.end(); ++it){
                if (comp(*t, *it))
                    stmp.insert(it->id);
            }
        }    

    return stmp;
}

class CharComparator
 {
   public:
               CharComparator ( bool caseSensitive = true ) 
                : m_CaseSensitive ( caseSensitive ) { }
    bool       operator () ( const char & a, const char & b ) const 
                { return m_CaseSensitive ? a == b : toupper (a) == toupper (b); }
   private:
    bool       m_CaseSensitive;  
 };

bool upperCaseCompare ( const char & a, const char & b )
 {
   return toupper ( a ) == toupper ( b );
 }

void printSet ( const set<int> & s )
 {
   for ( set<int>::const_iterator it = s . begin (); it != s . end (); ++it )
    cout << ( it == s . begin () ? "" : ", " ) << *it;
   cout << endl; 
 }

template <typename _T, int _N>
vector<_T> makeVector ( const _T (&data)[_N] )
 {
   return vector<_T> ( data, data + _N );
 } 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

CSearch <string> test1;
test1 . Add    ( 0, "hello" );
test1 . Add    ( 1, "world" );
test1 . Add    ( 2, "rld" );
test1 . Add    ( 3, "ell" );
test1 . Add    ( 4, "hell" );
printSet ( test1 . Search ( "hello world!" ) );
// 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
printSet ( test1 . Search ( "hEllo world!" ) );
// 1, 2

CSearch <string, bool (*)(const char &, const char &)> test2 ( upperCaseCompare );
test2 . Add    ( 0, "hello" );
test2 . Add    ( 1, "world" );
test2 . Add    ( 2, "rld" );
test2 . Add    ( 3, "ell" );
test2 . Add    ( 4, "hell" );
printSet ( test2 . Search ( "HeLlO WoRlD!" ) );
// 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
printSet ( test2 . Search ( "hallo world!" ) );
// 1, 2

CSearch <string, CharComparator> test3 ( CharComparator ( false ) );
test3 . Add    ( 0, "hello" );
test3 . Add    ( 1, "world" );
test3 . Add    ( 2, "rld" );
test3 . Add    ( 3, "ell" );
test3 . Add    ( 4, "hell" );
printSet ( test3 . Search ( "heLLo world!" ) );
// 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
printSet ( test3 . Search ( "Well, templates are hell" ) );
// 3, 4

CSearch <vector<int> > test4;
static const int needleA [] = { 1, 6, 1, 6, 9, 12 };
static const int needleB [] = { 9, 12, 7 };
static const int hayHeap [] = { 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 9, 12, 8 }; 
test4 . Add    ( 0, makeVector ( needleA ) );
test4 . Add    ( 1, makeVector ( needleB ) );
printSet ( test4 . Search ( makeVector ( hayHeap ) ) );
// 0

CSearch <vector<string> > test5;
static const string needleX  [] = { "Prague", "Bern", "Rome" };
static const string needleY  [] = { "London", "Prague", "Bern" };
static const string needleZ  [] = { "London", "Rome" };
static const string cityHeap [] = { "Berlin", "London", "Prague", "Bern", "Rome", "Moscow" }; 
test5 . Add    ( 0, makeVector ( needleX ) );
test5 . Add    ( 1, makeVector ( needleY ) );
test5 . Add    ( 2, makeVector ( needleZ ) );
printSet ( test5 . Search ( makeVector ( cityHeap ) ) );
// 0, 1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Names starting with underscore-capital are reserved for the implementation. Your program is thus ill-formed.

Comment: Why not just compare `*t` and `it->seq`?

Comment: It's a school assignment.Since the comparators are different, pass only a pointer to a function.

Comment: why not make comp a template function?

Comment: I added the prescribed test code. I can not change it, but the professor did.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way us to create an intermediary helper type with implicit conversion from both types.  Then write a comparison function or functor on it, and use that.

Comment: As it stands, this answer is more like a comment. The OP is unlikely to learn anything from it. Would you care to expand this a bit with some code suggestions?